# Use istio virtual service to expose 3 routes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio

We switch now to **istio** and I need to expose my app to outside

In the app, I've only 3 routes

> 1. "/" root route
> 2. "/login"
> 3. "static"  - my app should serve some static files

we have `gw` and `host` but somehow I cannot access my app, any idea what am I doing wrong here?
**vs-yaml**

is there a way to expose all the routes, or should I define them explicitly, if so how as it a bit confusing with `routes` and `match`?

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: bher-virtualservice
  namespace: ba-trail
spec:
  gateways:
    - webb-system.svc.cluster.local
  hosts:
    - trialio.cloud.str
  http:
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: bsa
            port:
              number: 5000
```

Comment: Can you post the gateway all please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if so how as it a bit confusing with routes and match

I would suggest to take a look at istio documentation about [virtual services](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/), it's well described there.

---

Let's start from the beginning, you have virtual service and gateway, they should be in the same namespace as your application, or you need to specify that in both of them.

As far as I can see your virtual service is incorrect, I have prepared example which should work for you. Take a look at below example.

**Gateway**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: bher-gateway
  namespace: ba-trail 
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use the default IngressGateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "trialio.cloud.str"
```

I see you have [gateway](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/gateway/) which is already deployed, if it´s not in the same namespace as virtual service, you should add it like in below example.

Check the `spec.gateways` section

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
name: my-gateway
namespace: some-config-namespace
```

---

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-Mongo
  namespace: bookinfo-namespace
spec:
  gateways:
  - some-config-namespace/my-gateway # can omit the namespace if gateway is in same
                                       namespace as virtual service.
```

---

**Virtual service**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: bher-virtualservice
  namespace: ba-trail 
spec:
  gateways:
    - bher-gateway   // name of your gateway 
  hosts:
    - trialio.cloud.str
  http:
    - match:
      - uri:
          prefix: "/"
      - uri:
          prefix: "/login"
      - uri:
          prefix: "/static"
      - uri:
          regex: '^.*\.(ico|png|jpg)$'
      route:
      - destination:
          host: bsa.ba-trail.svc.cluster.local   // name_of_your service.namespace.svc.cluster.local
          port:
            number: 5000
```

Take a look at this [example](https://rinormaloku.com/istio-practice-routing-virtualservices/)

> Let’s break down the requests that should be routed to Frontend:
>
> **Exact path** / should be routed to Frontend to get the Index.html
>
> **Prefix path** /static/* should be routed to Frontend to get any static files needed by the frontend, like **Cascading Style Sheets** and **JavaScript files**.
>
> **Paths matching the regex ^.*.(ico|png|jpg)$** should be routed to Frontend as it is an image, that the page needs to show.

```
http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /
    - uri:
        exact: /callback
    - uri:
        prefix: /static
    - uri:
        regex: '^.*\.(ico|png|jpg)$'
    route:
    - destination:
        host: frontend             
        port:
          number: 80
```

---

Hope you find this useful. If you have any questions let me know in the comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. im checking it now. one question the `host: frontend ` should be some arbitrary name or it should be related to some other property/key?

Comment: @Jenny M As I mentioned higher, it´s name of your service.

Comment: I must create a service? I mean `kind: service`

Comment: Yes, if you have a deployment, you need to crate a [kubernetes service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/). Take a look at istio [bookinfo example](https://istio.io/latest/docs/examples/bookinfo/) and the [deployments and services yamls](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.6/samples/bookinfo/platform/kube/bookinfo.yaml).

Comment: Then take a look at gateway and virtual service yamls [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.6/samples/bookinfo/networking/bookinfo-gateway.yaml). Virtual service host is productpage, that´s name of productpage service.

Comment: The whole process is request->ingress-gateway -> gateway -> virtual service -> optionally destination rule-> kubernetes service -> deployment.

Comment: one question, is there a way to get via kubectl command all the gateways i've in the cluster?

Comment: You can use `kubectl get gateways --all-namespaces` to get all gateways, if you´re looking for ingress/egress gateway then use `kubectl get pods -n istio-system`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and to see the content of the gw , is like this "kubectl get pod ide-wgateway -n ide -o yaml" ?

Comment: Exactly, or you can use `kubectl describe`.

Comment: Strange! , `I run the command 

kubectl get gateways --all-namespaces

I got  two entries

webi     webi1-sys-gateway   103d
webi2   webi2-wgateway             103d

Now I run the command 

 kubectl describe pod webi1-sys-gateway -n webi

I got error Error from server (NotFound): pods "webi1-sys-gateway" not found`

Comment: If they´re not in default namespace then you have to use `kubectl describe gateway name_of_gateway -n name_of_namespace`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've applied the vs, now I want to check it. I  run `kubectl get svc -n ns` when the app is located , and I didnt get externalip, how should I get the url to use outside ?

Comment: im able to access it with port-forward, but I want it to be available publicly

Comment: Can you please provide any hint?

Comment: it will be great if you can assist also here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63021871/istio-create-external-ip-for-specific-service

Comment: Sure, i left a comment in your second question.

Answer (score 1):

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: bher-virtualservice
  namespace: ba-trail
spec:
  gateways:
    - webb-system.svc.cluster.local.     #### don't look right , can write the gateway name only here.  ####
  hosts:
    - trialio.cloud.str
  http:
    - route:
        - destination:
            host: bsa
            port:
              number: 5000        ##  is your service working on this port 
    - rewrite:                    #### this should not be an issue but you can try adding this too
       uri: /
```