# istio create external ip for specific service

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, istio

I've deployed successfully an app to K8s with istio

We have gw which we use and virtual service like the following:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: bher-virtualservice
  namespace: ba-trail 
spec:
  gateways:
    - bher-gateway 
  hosts:
    - trialio.cloud.str
  http:
    - match:
      - uri:
          prefix: "/"
      - uri:
          prefix: "/login"
      - uri:
          prefix: "/static"
      - uri:
          regex: '^.*\.(ico|png|jpg)$'
      route:
      - destination:
          host: bsa.ba-trail.svc.cluster.local service.namespace.svc.cluster.local
          port:
            number: 5000
```

I defined also a `service` and `deployment`.

I want to expose the service outside that I will be able to access
like:

```sh
https://myapp.host:5000
```

when I run:

```sh
kubectl get svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system


NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                                                                  PORT(S)                                      AGE
istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   100.61.114.202   a7151b2063cb-200880.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com   150210:31161/TCP,80:31280/TCP,443:31190/TCP   41d
```

How it can be done?

I was able to run the app with port forwarding but I want a direct external link.

Comment: If you use istio then everything should go through istio-ingress-gateway external ip, so you should use `kubectl get svc -n istio-system`, check for istio ingress-gateway external ip and use it to get into your app from outside. If you use port-forwarding for your service then you´re not using istio, just your deployment service. By the way delete `service.namespace.svc.cluster.local` as it was commented to show you the syntax of route destination host.

Answer (score 2):

So in your case, you have an ELB serving your istio ingress gateway that goes to a VirtualService that directs traffic to port `5000` in the container.

I assume that you have it working with :

- `a7151b2063cb-200880.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com:80` and
- `a7151b2063cb-200880.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com:443` ❓

and you want something like:

- `a7151b2063cb-200880.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com:5000` ❓

but with a specific name that maps to

- `myapp.host` ❓

First, you have to create a DNS CNAME record that maps `myapp.host` to `a7151b2063cb-200880.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com`.

Then on the Kubernetes service `istio-ingressgateway` you probably have something like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: istio-ingressgateway
  namespace: istio-system
  labels:
    name: istio-ingress-service
  annotations:
    ... (❓)
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: ❓
    protocol: TCP
  - port: 443
    targetPort: ❓
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    name: something-that-matches-your-istio-ingress
```

You could just add the extra port to the service so that it listens on that port on the outside.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: istio-ingressgateway
  namespace: istio-system
  labels:
    name: istio-ingress-service
  annotations:
    ... (❓)
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: ❓
    protocol: TCP
  - port: 443
    targetPort: ❓
    protocol: TCP
  - port: 5000
    targetPort: ❓
  selector:
    name: something-that-matches-your-istio-ingress
```

Finally, the virtual service needs to match your hostname `myapp.host`

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: bher-virtualservice
  namespace: ba-trail 
spec:
  gateways:
    - bher-gateway 
  hosts:
    - myapp.host 
...
```

✌️

Comment: thanks 1+, some questions 1. what I want is something like "myapp.somehost:5000" so I must map the `somehost` to the `a7151b2063cb-200880.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com` , and how it will take the `myapp` from the `VS` hosts? , 2. are you sure that I need the `type: LoadBalancer` ,  when I did it before using istio is to expose my app outside, do I need it also when using istio?

Comment: yeah, you need the load balancer if you want to expose it from the outside. To expose your app you need an internal service with `ClusterIP`